# How to separate excel cell data the is in different lines( but in the same cell)

Tags: excel, text, cell

i have some data that i got from MAXQDA that gives me the file name, number of occurrences, group, etc.

The problem is that the data is all in the same cell but different lines.

i've tried text to columns but i can't find a way to separate the data by line.

i've got 700+ lines that are like  this:

`expresso\'Troika' elogia Governo
Document group: expresso
Document name: 'Troika' elogia Governo
Number of coded segments: 11`

i want one cell to get the document group, other with document name and another with number of coded segments

Comment: Solved!!!1. Select the entire area in Excel that includes translatable cells, then Copy (ctrl C)
2. Paste into an empty doc in Word (ctrl V)
3. Use the Find and Replace (ctrl H) function, press "Special" and select "Manual line break". There should be a "^l" appearing in the upper part of the Find and Replace dialogue (Replace:).
4. In the lower part (With:), enter a single space.
5. Press "Replace All".
6. Now all manual line breaks should be deleted in your text.
7. Select the entire cell area and paste it back into Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!

1st i replaced words that were common in all cell but that i didn't wanted for example document group in ≠ because it wasn't used anywhere.

!1. Select the entire area in Excel that includes translatable cells, then Copy (ctrl C)
2. Paste into an empty doc in Word (ctrl V)
3. Use the Find and Replace (ctrl H) function, press "Special" and select "Manual line break". There should be a "^l" appearing in the upper part of the Find and Replace dialogue (Replace:).
4. In the lower part (With:), enter a single space.
5. Press "Replace All".
6. Now all manual line breaks should be deleted in your text.
7. Select the entire cell area and paste it back into Excel.

to finish i used text to columns

works great!!!